# Passing arguments to a named function in an eventlistener using bind

Tags: javascript

Posted earlier on named functions in listeners, but it quickly changed focus as I understood more, so I thought I'd post something that now better reflects the question.

**What I'm trying to do:**

- Add listeners to a list of elements (done)
- Pass arguments to the callback in the listener (not working)
- Remove those listeners (done)

So point 1 & 3 need me to use a named function in the event listener, so I can refer to the same object when removing the listener.

For point 2, in order to pass extra arguments I'm using `bind`. Because it changes the method signature(?) of the callback, I store it in a separate variable `focusInHandler`. This works and the listener is removed when called.

However to get to my main question: **passing extra arguments currently isn't working**. I know that the first argument to `clearText` is the `event` object, and (afaik) `e.currentTarget` is equivalent to `this`, and `e.target` is the element that the event originated from,

but how can I access the additional arguments?

// index.js

```
adminView.addFocusInListeners(arrayOfElements, adminView.clearText);
```

// adminView.js

```
let focusInHandler;

export const addFocusInListeners = (items, cb) => {
    items.forEach(item => {
        focusInHandler = cb.bind(item, 'extra argument');
        item.addEventListener('focusin', cb);
    });
};
export const removeFocusInListeners = (items, cb) => {
    items.forEach(item => {
        focusInHandler = cb;
        item.removeEventListener('focusin', cb);
    });
}


export const clearText = (e, text) => {

    // e.currentTarget === this
    console.log(e.currentTarget);

    // e.target === the element clicked
    console.log(e.target);

    // undefined?
    console.log(text);
    console.log(this);
};
```

I'm probably missing something very simple, but this is as close as I've been able to get :(

Thanks!

Comment: You're not using `forcusInHandler` as the event listener.

Comment: `cb.bind()` returns a new function object every time you all it. Since this doesn't have a permanent name you can't refer to it in `removeEventListener`.

Comment: Nor are you properly storing the bound form in a way that you could remove it later. You'd have to either attach it to `item` itself or use a `item`-to-`focusInHandler` map.

Comment: Instead of adding and removing event listeners dynamically, it's usually easier to have the event listener function check whether it needs to do anything.

Comment: Why not use the DOM element data-* attribute to keep the data attached to the item? That way you use the same event listener for all the items.

Comment: @Barmar XD I have no ideal how I missed that, I must be tired! Ah, I see what you mean about `cb.bind` -> it's not being assigned to focusInHandler every time the callback is called is it? RE adding listeners dynamically -> yeah I'll try adding an event listener to the container, not sure why I'm not (again, probably just tired..) thanks!

Comment: @OluwafemiSule that's a good idea, thanks

Comment: Oh wow, yeah, rewriting it as a listener on the container - I *really* went about this the wrong way!

Answer (score 1):

[.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) **returns** a new function where `this` is your first argument. So you will have to add `focusInHandler` as your event listener.

Regarding removing and adding, you can keep pushing your event handlers to an array and use forEach with the right index to remove :

`forEach((element, index) => { ... } )`